# what is the fastest way to blur a listView when a dialog box is open?

Tags: android, listview, blur

After making some research i've found that I can take a screenshot of the existing view on the screen and blur the bitmap of it but that takes around 0.2 seconds, I need to find a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` is deprecated.
You can dim the background behind if you want fast results,
Or blur by taking a bitmap snapshot as you mentioned (bad performance).

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x8000000));
```